# How to transform a mathematical expression from LaTeX code to Maxima code?

Tags: conversion, code

How to transform a mathematical expression from LaTeX code to Maxima code?

For example, convert

```
\frac{8x^3-4x-2}{2x}
```

in LaTeX to

```
(8*x^3-4*x-2)/(2*x)
```

in Maxima, but automatically.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm inclined to think this is a problem in Maxima, not in TeX. Or do you want to show Maxima code in TeX from the TeX code?

Comment: In Mathematica (not Maxima), you have `ToExpression["\\frac{8x^3-4x-2}{2x}", TeXForm] // InputForm`, which gives `(-2 - 4*x + 8*x^3)/(2*x)` (turns out that in this case the syntax is compatible). I doubt there is a similar tool in Maxima, even in Mathematica it is not bullet proof.